# Is it OK to choose an accepted answer but grant the bounty to an other

Tags: discussion, bounty

An example for that is what I have done today
[Is a biometric eye scan more secure than a multi-factor authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65543/is-a-biometric-eye-scan-more-secure-than-a-multi-factor-authentication)

I have started the bounty as the question didn't get enough attention, I genuinely thought I needed a discussion/ an answer about the priority of one type of authentication compared to an other but PwdRsch's answer lead to the conclusions that the answer I needed was not what I expected

tylerl gave the best answer from security point of view but I handed the bounty to PwdRsch's answer as it was the most useful for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is that you accept the answer that is most helpful to you, but you can award your bounty to any answer (it makes sense to award it to one that is of value, obviously, but it is your bounty to do with what you will)

So I'd suggest in future you could do things the other way round, but in this instance I wouldn't worry about it.

Remember, rep is only magic unicorn points :-)

Comment: "rep is only magic unicorn points" so that means that I can't buy anything with it? *walks away*

Comment: With enough rep you can buy the grovelling of weakly-minded users, who are prone to be overawed by big numbers.

Comment: I think Ulkoma should be free to treat it the way they did.  The accepted answer should be the one most likely to help the average reader.  The bounty is for you to give out for being helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

The [official recommendation](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for accepting answers is

> Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

The accepted answer is the one that shows up at the top of the answer list for visitors. It's generally best to accept the answer that provides the best overview of the topic. The choice of accepted answer influences how all visitors will perceive the thread.

A bounty is largely a matter between the bounty giver and the recipient; the bounty is indicated next to the answer, which indicates that there may be something particularly useful there, but it doesn't make the answer stand out very much. It's mostly a reward for an outstanding answer.

Some bounties are naturally awarded to the accepted answer, if it provides exceptionally good coverage of the topic or a clever, useful solution. At other times, a bounty rewards an outstanding, but partial answer, for example a detailed treatment of one of the aspects of the problem, or a clever solution that only works in special cases; in such cases, it's natural to award a bounty to an answer without accepting it.